# Changing command button colors

Tags: excel, vba

I'm hoping someone can help me since I am new at VBA. I have a spreadsheet with 200 command buttons on it. I want to be able to change the backcolor of a button based on the value in a cell. The names for the 200 buttons are FACopy1 through FACopy200. The code below works for changing a specific button (in this case FACopy1).

```
    ActiveSheet.FACopy1.BackColor = RGB(0, 255, 255)
```

However, I want the button that changes to be based on a cell value. For example, If the cell value is 7 then it will change the color of FACopy7. I want something like this:

```
    ActiveSheet.FACopy(cell value).BackColor = RGB(0, 255, 255)
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work.
Modify to suit your needs

```
Sub Test1()
Dim cb As CommandButton
Dim x As Integer
x = Range("A1") * 1
Set cb = ActiveSheet.Shapes("FACopy" & x).OLEFormat.Object.Object
            cb.BackColor = RGB(0, 255, 255)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you John! That worked perfect! I really appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
Sub test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim btn As OLEObject
    Dim i As Integer
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    For i = 1 To 200
        Set btn = ws.OLEObjects("FACopy" & i)
        btn.Object.BackColor = RGB(200, 255, 255)
    Next i
    
End Sub
```